# Bokeh - create a fixed label when point clicked

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there any way to be able to click a point in a plot and have the label be fixed so that a link in the label can be clicked?

I have tried this using HoverTool() but it only shows the label during a hover and then the label disappears.

Here is an example similar to what I am using Bokeh for: https://www.kaggle.com/ykhorramz/lda-and-t-sne-interactive-visualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing built-in right now. It's tracked in this issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5724
There's also a workaround there, but it may be outdated a bit.